# Can Magento create a auto selecting product listing?

Tags: product, product-list, magento-1.9, dropdown-attribute

The idea is to have a drop down menu of several items which require numerous components for their installation. Once one option is selected (e.g. item A) all the necessary components required for its installation (there are roughly 8) will be listed below and included in a total price. Currently I have created drop down menus for the items and each component however they require manual selection and without detailed knowledge of the item, the compatible components are not obvious. 
Is it possible to set up a product listing in this format using magento 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you want to create a configurable option where each simple product added is a possible combination of compatible parts. Then the user can choose desired options and only be shown the compatible part for the next decision.

more about configurable products can be found [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product)